# Ruby Methods: how to return an usage string when insufficient arguments are given

Tags: ruby, error-handling, methods, arguments, initialization

After I have created a serious bunch of classes (with initialize methods), I am loading these into IRb to test each of them. I do so by creating simple instances and calling their methods to learn their behavior. However sometimes I don't remember exactly what order I was supposed to give the arguments when I call the .new method on the class. It requires me to look back at the code. However, I think it should be easy enough to return a usage message, instead of seeing:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 9)
```

So I prefer to return a string with the human readable arguments, by example using "puts" or just a return of a string. Now I have seen the rescue keyword inside begin-end code, but I wonder how I could catch the ArgumentError when the initialize method is called.

Thank you for your answers, feedback and comments!

Comment: My sincere apologies if my questions are difficult to read, English is not my native language.

Comment: Your English in this question was fine. No problems understanding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to hook into object creation by overriding the `Class#new` method e.g.

```
class Class
  # alias the original 'new' method before overriding it
  alias_method :old_new, :new
  def new(*args)
    return old_new(*args)
    rescue ArgumentError => ae          
      if respond_to?(:usage)
        raise ArgumentError.new(usage)
      else 
        raise ae
      end
  end
end
```

This overriden method calls the normal `new` method but catches `ArgumentError` and if the class of the object being created provides a `usage` method then it will raise an `ArgumentError` with the usage message otherwise it will reraise the original `ArgumentError`.

Here is an example of it in action. Define a `Person` class:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name, age)
  end

  def self.usage
    "Person.new should be called with 2 arguments: name and age"
  end
end
```

and then try and instantiate it without the required arguments:

```
irb(main):019:0> p = Person.new
ArgumentError: Person.new should be called with 2 arguments: name and age
    from (irb):8:in `new'
    from (irb):22
```

*Note*: this isn't perfect. The main problem being that it is possible that the `ArgumentError` we catch has been caused by something other than an incorrect number of arguments being passed to `initialize` which would lead to a misleading message. However it should do what you want in most cases.

Comment: I like both answers, especially that I know that you can override the new method / class constructor. However the second one is clearly simplistic enough to serve my needs. Thank you so much!